# An Answer Just Disappeared

Tags: discussion

Someone posted an answer on my question: [Where should I place jQuery Mobile pages generated dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145936/where-should-i-place-jquery-mobile-page-generated-dynamically) and it has suddenly vanished. It had no down-votes.

Is there a way I can see if the author removed the answer, or if a moderator removed it?

Thanks.

Comment: Only 10k+ users can see deleted answers. Most likely, it wouldn't be very useful for you if the author decided to delete it.

Comment: @codeMagic Thanks for your reply. Is there any way I (or someone else) can find out if it was deleted by the author or by a moderator?

Comment: It was deleted by the author.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thanks for your reply. I will wait for another answer.

Comment: Worth noting that it was deleted after you posted a comment asking for further clarification - you may wish to edit your question to elaborate on how much information you need, to avoid further confusion in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a way to see whether the author or a moderator removed the answer.

That way is to **get 10,000 reputation** so that you can see deleted posts

BTW, it was deleted by the author.